# Magnific Popup - start gallery from second array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup

I'd like to learn how to modify Magnific Popup code to control the array of images created to start a gallery not from item 0 (first image of the gallery)  but from 1 (second image of the gallery). I need to make small change of the logic in the gallery. The current behavior is when one of thumbnails clicked from gallery the pop up window gallery is launched with the image of the thumbnail clicked. I need to make the next image in the gallery from that array is loaded instead. Let say. I have a gallery of 4 images. The thumbnail is the first image from the gallery. On click I need to load a second image from the gallery. Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Here is the function code.

```html
function lightbox() {
        $('.lightbox').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            gallery:{
                enabled:true,
                arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"><img src="img/assets/slider-left-thin-arrow.png"></button>',
            },
            mainClass: 'mfp-zoom-in',
            removalDelay: 500, //delay removal to allow out-animation
            callbacks: {
                beforeOpen: function() {
                    this.st.image.markup = this.st.image.markup.replace('mfp-figure', 'mfp-figure mfp-with-anim');
                }
            },     
            closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close"></button>',
            midClick: true
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `beforeOpen` callback , get instance and call `next()` on the instance

```
callbacks: {
  beforeOpen: function() {
    var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance; // instance of magnificPopup
    mfp.next();
  }
}
```

UPDATE:  If the first item should not be displayed then no need of `next()`just splice it out of the `items` array and indexes will be good

```
callbacks: {
    beforeOpen: function() {
      var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance; // instance of magnificPopup    
      mfp.items.splice(0, 1);
      mfp.updateItemHTML();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Novice! I was able to advance to the next item instance. Below is the code. I had to modify 'function(e)' to function() and it started to work correctly.

However, I need to remove the first item from the array collection at all. what would be the best solution to achieve that? Thank you again!

```html
function lightbox() {
        $('.lightbox').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            gallery:{
                enabled:true,
                arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"><img src="img/assets/slider-left-thin-arrow.png"></button>',
            },
            mainClass: 'mfp-zoom-in',
            removalDelay: 500, //delay removal to allow out-animation
            callbacks: {
                beforeOpen: function() {
     var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance; 
        mfp.next();
                    this.st.image.markup = this.st.image.markup.replace('mfp-figure', 'mfp-figure mfp-with-anim');
                }
            },     
            closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close"></button>',
            midClick: true
        });
    }
```

Thank you!